# Is it possible to get a list of the installed browsers using dart:io?

Tags: dart, grinder

Is it possible to get a list of the installed browsers using `dart:io` ?

More specifically, I would want to have a variable 
`List installedBrowsers` in my grinder file, so that my grinder will work independently of the OS and installed browsers.

```
@DefaultTask('Test')
test() =>
    new TestRunner().test(
        files: myFile,
        platformSelector: installedBrowsers);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `which` to find executables with a certain name. 
Alternatively you can require one or more specific environment variables to be set to get the browser names and/or executable paths of the available browsers.